# Facebook multi-friend-selector always displays email invite section

Tags: facebook, fbml, invite

I managed to get fb:multi-friend-selector working. However after choosing friends and sending invitations to them there is a popup "Optional: also send to email contacts?" displayed which I don't want.

According to the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector there is a email_invite flag indicating whether this popup should be displayed or not.

For me it's always displayed no matter if I set email_invite="true" or email_invite="false".

Anyone knows how to get rid of this popup?

Below is the code I generate:

```
<fb:serverfbml>
  <script type='text/fbml'>
    <fb:request-form 
      action="http://example.com" 
      content="Your friend invites you to Test site &lt;fb:req-choice label=&quot;Accept&quot; url=&quot;http://example.com/&quot; /&gt;" 
      invite="true" 
      method="post" 
      type="Test site">
      <fb:multi-friend-selector 
        actiontext="Invite your friends to Test site" 
        bypass="cancel" 
        condensed="false" 
        email_invite="false" 
        exclude_ids="" 
        max="20" 
        showborder="true" />
    </fb:request-form>
  </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and added the parameters to remove the popup :

email_invite=false
import_external_friends=false

ie.

```
<fb:serverfbml>
  <script type='text/fbml'>
    <fb:request-form 
      action="http://example.com" 
      content="Your friend invites you to Test site &lt;fb:req-choice label=&quot;Accept&quot; url=&quot;http://example.com/&quot; /&gt;" 
      invite="true" 
      method="post" 
      type="Test site">
      <fb:multi-friend-selector 
        actiontext="Invite your friends to Test site" 
        bypass="cancel" 
        condensed="false" 
        email_invite=false
        import_external_friends=false
        exclude_ids="" 
        max="20"
        showborder="true" />
    </fb:request-form>
  </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```